# Product Name not updating

Tags: installshield

I had set the product name here:

[image]

And it's clearly listed in the direct editor,

But now after a successful build any reference to ProductName refers to the old product name I had, before changing it.

It's like InstallShield is ignoring my product name change.

How can this be fixed, or do I need to recreate the entire project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product name in the release media was overwriting the one set in the project.